# Multiple Tables with Multiple Rows Update via SQL Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel

I have a MySQL database setup like so:

- Events table (with an ID primary key)
- Line Items (with lineItemID primary key, eventID foreign key)
- GivenLineItemFunds (with lineItemId Primary&foreign key)

When an admin is reviewing a submitted event, he/she sees this:
[image: Admin interface of form/table]

An admin will enter in "funds given," for each row and then submit. Right now I have the system setup as a paginated system, but I may switch to having all the tables/'events' on one page.

How should I setup my form to take the LineItemID value for each row and submit it with the fundsGiven field to the database? Should I be doing this via Ajax? Am I just over complicating this?

Answer (score 0):

When building the form, I would just set the `name` attribute of the `<input>` to the lineItemID (or 'item' . lineItemID)

```
{{ Form::text($lineItem->name, null, array(
  'name' => 'item' . $lineItem->lineItemId
)) }}
```

Comment: Then when looping input, just use the "name" as a value for one column, then the value of the input as the other column?

Comment: @dsgunter basically; that seems like the easiest way